# Database error conection using django-mssql-backend

Tags: django, pyodbc, django-mssql-backend

I have to update an old django proyect that use `django 1.8`, `pyodbc 3.0.10` and `django-pyodbc-azure 1.8.3.0` with `python 2.7.11`. For the new version I need to use `django 3.1.3`, `pyodbc 4.0.30` and `django-mssql-backend 2.8.1` with `python 3.9.0` the main difference is the use of `django-mssql-backend 2.8.1` instead of `django-pyodbc-azure 1.8.3.0`, my `settings.py` have this configuration:

```
'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'dn_name',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'host\instance',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0',
            'unicode_results': True,
        },
    },
```

Using the old version the connection works correctly but when I update the proyect gives me this error:

> ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]TCP
> Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine
> actively refused it.  (10061) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001]
> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired (0);
> [08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid connection
> string attribute (0); [08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client
> 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not
> accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
> configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL
> Server Books Online. (10061)')

For what I know I have the correct configuration. Somebody knows if I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the `'PORT': '1433'` parameter I use `'PORT': ''` and that solve the problem